# Execute a task after queue completion in laravel

Tags: laravel, queue

I have a queue like the following in `laravel`,

```
Mail::queue($notificationCreated->template, $data, function ($message) use ($data) {
$message->to($data['email'], $data['first_name'])->subject($data['subject']);
});
```

Is it possible to execute a task after queue completes it's execution, i.e in my case after sending a mail.

Comment: Why don't you send email directly at the end of your queue listener?

Comment: Email is sent in the queue itself, i want to execute a task after queue completes it's execution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this is not present in the API because that's not the point of `Queue`.

It's *asynchronous* so after calling `Mail::queue` you immediately get back control and code execution continues. That does not mean the actual job has been executed, just that it's been scheduled.
And there's no way of writing a `Mail::whenJobIsComplete` there because that would mean the whole execution of your code would have to stop and wait for the job to be completed. There no way this could work *asynchronously*.

You could however periodically *poll* for completed jobs and execute code when that happens. There's [build-in](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#failed-jobs) functionality for polling for failed jobs in the API.

But the best approach would be to write your own custom [queue listener](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/queues#running-the-queue-listener),
and adding functionality besides the `handleWorkerOutput` [call](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/5.0/src/Illuminate/Queue/Listener.php#L93).
Again, this is asynchronous, this code will run at some indeterminate point in the future, not even close to the place where you initially called `Mail::queue`.